# Can I get emcc to support initializer-lists?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, emscripten

The feature mentioned in the title is being used often in my code-base, which I thought to be relatively standard. Now I am surprised negatively that the emcc compiler can't seem to handle it.

I would like to do something like this:

```
unsigned char PermutationTable[256] = {
    151,160,137,91,90,15,131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,
    8,99,37,240,21,10,23,190,6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,
    35,11,32,57,177,33,88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168,68,175,74,165,71,
    134,139,48,27,166,77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,
    55,46,245,40,244,102,143,54,65,25,63,161,1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208,89,
    18,169,200,196,135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186,3,64,52,217,226,
    250,124,123,5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,
    189,28,42,223,183,170,213,119,248,152,2,44,154,163,70,221,153,101,155,167, 
    43,172,9,129,22,39,253,19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185,112,104,218,246,
    97,228,251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241,81,51,145,235,249,14,239,
    107,49,192,214,31,181,199,106,157,184,84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127,4,150,254,
    138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180};
```

Or this:

```
struct color
    {
    float Red;
    float Green;
    float Blue;
    };

void DrawRectangle (float X = 0.0f, float Y = 0.0f, color C = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f})
    {
    ...
    }
```

But apparently emcc is not OK with that: `error: expected expression`, pointing to the first occurrence of `{`.

Hopefully there's a solution that does not involve me rewriting lots of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to compile your code with **-std=c++11** option.